# $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and assumes one single critical point at $x = c$ that is a local minimum. Prove that $f(c)$ is the absolute minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was working on a textbook problem yesterday when I found myself needing to prove a statement to make my main argument more rigorous. The statement seems relatively simple at first, yet I ended up with a rather lengthy proof involving an additional lemma, which itself was not as straightforward as I had anticipated either. I understand that basic-looking statements can sometimes require long arguments, but I was wondering if there might be a more efficient approach that I've overlooked. As someone relatively new to writing proofs, I would greatly appreciate any feedback on my proofs too! Thank you very much!

> Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and have one single critical point in $(a, b)$ at $x = c$, with $f(c)$ being a local minimum. Prove that $f(c)$ is the absolute minimum of $f(x)$.

**Lemma:** Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and have no critical points in $(a, b).$ Then $f(x)$ is strictly monotone over $[a, b].$

*Proof:*

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. Assume that $f(x)$ has no critical points in $(a,b)$, which implies $f'(x)$ exists and $f'(x) \neq 0$ or all $x \in (a,b)$. By Fermat's theorem, $f(x)$ does not have a local extremum in $(a, b).$

Let $c, d \in [a, b]$ such that $c < d.$ Suppose it is not the case that $f(x)$ strictly decreases on $[c, d].$ That is, $f(c) \leq f(d).$ Our goal is to prove that $f(x)$ strictly increases on $[c, d].$ That is, $f(c) < f(d).$

By the Extreme Value Theorem, $f(x)$ has its minimum and maximum on $[c, d].$ Since neither can occur in $(c,d)$ (as otherwise it would imply an extremum exists in $(a, b)$), both the maximum and minimum must occur at the endpoints $c, d.$ If $f(c) = f(d)$, $f(x)$ is constant on $[c, d],$ which implies that $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (a, c),$ a contradiction. It follows that $f(c) < f(d).$ Hence, $f(x)$ is strictly monotone over $[a, b].$

**Proposition:** Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and have one single critical point in $(a, b)$ at $x = c$, with $f(c)$ being a local minimum. Prove that $f(c)$ is the absolute minimum of $f(x)$.

*Proof:*

Assume that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and has a local minimum at $c \in (a, b)$, which implies that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in [a, b], |x  - c| < \delta \implies f(x) \geq f(c).$

$f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, c]$ and has no critical points in $(a, c).$ By our lemma, $f(x)$ is strictly monotone over $[a, c].$

Suppose that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[a, c].$ Then $f(x) < f(c)$ for all $x \in (c - \delta, c) \cap (a, b)$ for any $\delta > 0,$ contradicting our original assumption. It follows that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[a, c].$ Hence, $f(c) < f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, c).$

A similar argument shows that  $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[c, b],$ which implies that $f(c) < f(x)$ for all $x \in (c, b].$

Since $f(c) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b],$ $f(c)$ is the absolute minimum of $f(x).$

**EDIT1:** I just realized that it's not sufficient to prove that $f(x)$ is increasing just by showing that $f(a) < f(c) < f(b)$ for all $c < (a, b).$ I'm having dinner and thinking about it. Hope to update soon!

**EDIT2:** I just revised my first proof!

Comment: Hi, what is a "critical point" for a continuous point? Do you also assume that $f$ is differentiable? In that case, I guess you can use the theorem of intermediate values for $f'$ (Darboux theorem).

Comment: @TrivialPursuit Hello, I'm not sure I understand your first question, but a "critical point" is defined as a point at which the derivative is undefined or equal to $0.$ And no, it is not assumed in either statement that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere in the open interval $(a,b),$ though for the first statement I believe (and did show above) that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere in $(a, b).$ Sorry but I'm not sure I understand your 2nd point either. Could you pls post an outline of such an approach? Thank you!

Comment: I think you can prove it along the lines of: derivative of $f$ exists for all $x \in (a,b)-\{c\}$. Then, we must have $f'(x) < 0$ for points to the left of $c$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for points to the right of $c$ (use local minimum assumption and that $f'(x) = 0$ only possible at $x=c$). Thus, $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[a, c)$ and strictly increasing on $(c,b]$. Then, $f(c)$ must be the global minimum.

Comment: @hff1 Hi, your approach sounds like what I did above. In my opinion, it would entail proving an additional lemma (as shown above), which is what you said, "we must have $f'(c) < 0$ for points to the left of $c$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for points to the right of $c$," which is essentially that f(x) must be monotone on each side. It seems this is not something that follows immediately from $f'(x) \neq 0$ (i.e. there could be a mix of intervals where $f'(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) < 0$ on each side, which must be shown to be impossible). My proof for the lemma above is incorrect though and I'm fixing it :D.

Comment: @ten_to_tenth Use the intermediate value theorem for derivatives (Darboux's theorem), if the sign of the derivative changes in e.g.$[a, c)$, then there must be a point $m \in [a, c)$ such that $f'(m) = 0$. Can you derive a contradiction from here?

Comment: @hff1 Wouldn't that imply that the derivative function is also continuous, which is not assumed?

Comment: Btw, I just revised my first proof. I hope you could take a look too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $c$ is different from a global minimum $d$.  Consider a connected neighborhood $U$ of $c$ where $c$ is a local minimum, which is sufficiently small so that $d\not\in U$.  Since $c$ is the unique critical point in $(a,b)$, there are must be a point $e\in U$ between $c$ and $d$ where $f(e)>f(c)$.  In the interval with endpoints $c$ and $d$ (in whichever order), there is a global maximum $g$.  Since $f(g)\geq f(e)>f(c)$, the point $g$ is distinct from the endpoints $c$ and $d$.  Thus $g$ is another critical point, contradicting the hypothesis that $c$ is the unique critical point in $(a,b)$.

Comment: This is brilliant!!! Thank you so much!